# Kibana - get logs surrounding certain document with patterns to mark start and end range of a context

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

For example, I see an error log in Kibana, but I am not interested only in this error, but also the context of this line, i.e., I want to know what happens before and after this error. Such as:

- the order failed with status "FAILED", but the log just before this line would contain the method name who caused this error
- some 5-10 lines before this, I know there would be a line like "Start processing order xxxxx with status xxx"
- and 15-20 lines after this log, there would be something like "End processing with status xxx"

All this together, marks a life cycle of processing of this particular order. And all these lines are what I mean by saying "context".

How can I get all these lines as a search in Kibana?(Let's suppose all the literals are in the field "message")

For now, I know we can "view surrounding documents", but that is not efficient enough.

Comment: It sounds like you have an order number. When processing logs through logstash or whatever ingestion pipeline it may be helpful to create a field (ex: `orderNum`), which can then be searched in kibana to fetch all the logs associated with that order number.

Comment: Ye, but not every log about this order has this orderNum. Otherwise it would be easier. I want a context with certain start pattern, and then all logs from all classes are probably about this order(there could be logs of another order because of concurrency), till the end pattern. They are chronological.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/xpack-apm.html

Well, just learn about Elastic APM and it can solve part of the problem. APM can record "span" and "transactions" to form "distributed trace", then add info to the field "trace" to logs and then we can aggregate all logs with same trace id to learn the context of this event across the microservices.

The question now changes to "How to use APM to add trace". And, one of our microservices is reactive, which cannot be easily adapted to use APM: Reactive pipeline context is thread-based, between the threads there are no easy way to transfer the trace from one context to another. So this is the part APM cannot solve.

But at least now we know in imperative apps we have a way.

Comment: Can't we solve all those if we use Correlation-Id? Suppose the example given in the question, all the logs will write the same Correlation-Id in a single request. We also can include this Correlation-Id when we publish events so that other microservice can also write that Correlation-Id. In this way, in kibana we can find the trace of the whole lifecycle of a user's action.

Comment: Cannot say about that one, as I see it among the fields but never got a chance to know how to add info there. If you know how to add it in all requests, please post an answer.

Comment: It's basically a common practice in Microservice architecture. There are plenty of resources if you google no matter what technology stack you are using, for example, you may have a look at this. 
https://dzone.com/articles/correlation-id-for-logging-in-microservices

Comment: OK thanks. If that is the solution would be very good.